# Django form POST with NoReverseMatch error

Tags: django, forms, post

In html:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="{% url 'myapp:add_review' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input id="review" name="review" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

In views:

```
def add_reviews(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print "Post is here:", request.POST['review']
        return render(request, 'myapp/single_item.html')
        //or this?? return redirect('myapp:single_item')
```

In urls.py

```
app_name = 'myapp'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

    # register, login, logout
    url(r'^register/$', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_user, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_user, name='logout'),

    # individual article page
    url(r'^(?P<item_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.single_item, name='single_item'),
    url(r'^(?P<item_id>[0-9]+)/add_review/$', views.add_review, name='add_review'),
]
```

Really basic stuff, in each individual item page, I want a form to write and post reviews for each item, and go back to the same item page.

When I'm in the individual item page, gives me the following error:

```
Reverse for 'add_review' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 
1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<item_id>[0-9]+)/add_review/$']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, these types of errors indicate that something is not right with an URL, that such pattern was not found, that it misses some parameters and so forth. From this particular error it seems that you are not passing `item_id` to the url matcher. Hence, Django cannot find an appropriate URL. You have:

```
url(r'^(?P<item_id>[0-9]+)/add_review/$', views.add_review, name='add_review')
```

Notice that you wrote `?P<item_id>[0-9]+)/...`, which means you must provide `item_id` whenever you want this URL to be resolved. Try adding `item_id` as a keyword argument:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="{% url 'myapp:add_review' item_id= ... %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

This should construct a valid url (e.g., `.../1/add_review/`), which should be recognised by Django. However, I believe your `add_review()` function will also need to take an `item_id` argument, otherwise you might get `TypeError` due to unexpected function arguments.

As for the return value, I would use `redirect` instead of `render`, as you are, well, redirecting after a successful POST. Though you might need to pass a `item_id`, too, since your URL config specifies that: a) URL should have `item_id` and b) `single_item()` expects `item_id`. Something like this should work:

```
def add_review(request, item_id):
    ...
    return redirect('myapp:single_item', {'item_id': item_id})
```

And signature of `single_item` should be something like this: `single_item(request, item_id)`.

Comment: I knew it was something wrong with the id part, couldn't figure out where and how. Thank you for the detailed explanation, totally make sense to me now.